# Удаление ненужных значений в запросе

Tags: 1с

Есть документ с реквизитом "Организация", который в свою очередь ссылается на справочник с организациями. Я хочу в запросе брать реквизит документа, но чтобы в него не попадала определенная организация.

То есть допустим в справочнике лежат организации "Мышка", "Кошка", "Кролик", "Собака". Запрос должен взять все, кроме "Собака". Как это осуществить? (подойдет любое решение: как в самом тексте запроса, так и в последующем коде).

Answer (score 2):

В 1С есть механизм который называется "Разделение данных" см
https://v8.1c.ru/platforma/razdelenie-dannyh/
Кроме этого, если речь идет о скрытии данных "для разных юзеров" есть RLS
https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev#content:2316:hdoc
И наконец, если речь идет о модификации запросе, необходимо добавить к нему соответствующее условие:

```
ВЫБРАТЬ * ИЗ Справочник.МойСправочник ГДЕ НЕ Организация.Наименование = "Собака"  
// Через параметр  
ВЫБРАТЬ * ИЗ Справочник.МойСправочник ГДЕ НЕ Организация = &Организация
```